# Here maps api for geocoder doesn't get the area shape for district

Tags: here-api, geocoder

I used this Here Geocode API to get the area shapes for the district. However, there's no available shapes being returned on the API.

here is the link for the API

```
https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.xml?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&apiKey=<APIKEY>&searchtext=Cakung%20Barat%20Kel.%20Jakarta%2013910%20Indonesia&mode=retrieveAddresses&jsoncallback=H.service.jsonp.handleResponse(37)&gen=9&additionalData=IncludeShapeLevel,district
```

here is the response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Search xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Search-Search/4">
    <Response>
        <MetaInfo>
            <Timestamp>2021-07-28T10:09:26.934Z</Timestamp>
        </MetaInfo>
        <View xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:SearchResultsViewType">
            <ViewId>0</ViewId>
            <Result>
                <Relevance>1.0</Relevance>
                <MatchLevel>district</MatchLevel>
                <MatchQuality>
                    <Country>1.0</Country>
                    <City>1.0</City>
                    <Subdistrict>1.0</Subdistrict>
                    <PostalCode>1.0</PostalCode>
                </MatchQuality>
                <Location>
                    <LocationId>NT_ezpLZJFGXsz2rWjEVeA2oD</LocationId>
                    <LocationType>area</LocationType>
                    <DisplayPosition>
                        <Latitude>-6.16492</Latitude>
                        <Longitude>106.93429</Longitude>
                    </DisplayPosition>
                    <NavigationPosition>
                        <Latitude>-6.16492</Latitude>
                        <Longitude>106.93429</Longitude>
                    </NavigationPosition>
                    <MapView>
                        <TopLeft>
                            <Latitude>-6.1516</Latitude>
                            <Longitude>106.92209</Longitude>
                        </TopLeft>
                        <BottomRight>
                            <Latitude>-6.19349</Latitude>
                            <Longitude>106.94349</Longitude>
                        </BottomRight>
                    </MapView>
                    <Address>
                        <Label>Cakung Barat Kel., Cakung, Jakarta, Indonesia</Label>
                        <Country>IDN</Country>
                        <County>DKI Jakarta</County>
                        <City>Jakarta</City>
                        <District>Cakung</District>
                        <Subdistrict>Cakung Barat Kel.</Subdistrict>
                        <PostalCode>13910</PostalCode>
                        <AdditionalData key="CountryName">Indonesia</AdditionalData>
                        <AdditionalData key="CountyName">DKI Jakarta</AdditionalData>
                    </Address>
                </Location>
            </Result>
        </View>
    </Response>
</ns2:Search>
```

it is working for city and other options. based from the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/example-geocode-retrieve-shape-area.html), district is included on valid shape levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tried to reproduce the request but it was determined as the coverage range is not supportive to get district-level shape for Jakarta.

For Example,
Demo link: https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/admin_boundaries

Also, we have documentation information with regards to coverage range.

Link: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/coverage-geocoder.html